# How to load a user before the page loads

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication, next.js

## Main Question

I have an Auth Provider which wraps around my entire _app.tsx file. This allows me to use the "useAuth" hook and get access to the user object from any file in my app. However, I have a problem when using this hook to conditionally load my Navbar. For the first few seconds of the page-load, there is no user object found, this causes my logged out component to flash on the screen for a second. Then the user object is found and the correct component is loaded. I am not sure how to solve this issue? I have researched many different methods to solve this issue. GetInitialProps, GetServerSideProps... I am not sure what will work.

### [Edit] - Question Clarification

- How do you make sure a firebase user is loaded before a component loads in Next.js?

### Tech Stack Used

- Next.js
- Firebase Auth
- MongoDB

## Gif of the issue

[gif showing the flashing navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwCCs.gif)

## Code

### _app.tsx

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <Global
                styles={css`
                    button {
                        border: none;
                    }
                    input {
                        border: none;
                    }
                `}
            />
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CSSReset />
                <AuthProvider>
                    <Page>
                        <Navbar />
                        <Component {...pageProps} />

                        <Footer />
                    </Page>
                </AuthProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

### AuthContext.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import nookies from 'nookies';
import { firebase } from './initFirebase';
import initFirebase from './initFirebase';
import { auth } from 'firebase';

const AuthContext = createContext<{ user: firebase.User | null }>({
    user: null,
});

export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        return firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                setUser(null);
                nookies.set(undefined, 'token', '', {});
                return;
            }

            const token = await user.getIdToken();
            setUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
            nookies.set(undefined, 'token', token, {});
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

// signOut function
export const signOut = async () => {
    await auth().signOut();
};

// useAuth hook
export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

### Navbar component

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const { user} = useAuth();
    const [loggedOut, setLoggedOut] = useState(false);
    const toast = useToast();
    const router = useRouter();
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

    const handleSignOut = () => {
        signOut()
            .then((result) => {
                toast({
                    title: 'Signed Out',
                    description: 'You have successfully signed out of your account.',
                    status: 'success',
                    duration: 4000,
                    isClosable: true,
                    position: 'top',
                });
                setLoggedOut(true);
                router.push('/');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                toast({
                    title: errorCode,
                    description: errorMessage,
                    status: 'error',
                    duration: 4000,
                    isClosable: true,
                    position: 'top',
                });
            });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <NavbarWrapper>
                <NavbarElementWrapper>
                    <LogoLink>
                        <Link href='/'>
                            <Logo />
                        </Link>
                    </LogoLink>
                </NavbarElementWrapper>

                {user ? (
                    <SplitLinks>
                        <NavbarElementWrapper>
                            <TimelineModal />
                        </NavbarElementWrapper>

                        <Menu>
                            <Tooltip label='Account Details' aria-label='account details'>
                                <MenuButton style={{ outline: 'none' }}>
                                    <Avatar
                                        src={user.photoURL}
                                        name={user.displayName || user.email.split('@')[0]}
                                    />
                                </MenuButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                            <MenuList>
                                <MenuGroup>
                                    <MenuItem onClick={() => onOpen()} height='100%'>
                                        <Box as={FaUser} mr='12px' />
                                        Account
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem onClick={() => router.push('/timelines')} height='100%'>
                                        <Box as={MdTimeline} mr='12px' />
                                        Timelines
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <MenuDivider />
                                    <MenuItem justifyContent='center' style={{ background: 'none' }}>
                                        <Button
                                            onClick={handleSignOut}
                                            leftIcon='arrow-forward'
                                            variantColor='red'
                                        >
                                            Sign Out
                                        </Button>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </MenuGroup>
                            </MenuList>
                        </Menu>
                    </SplitLinks>
                ) : (
                    <SplitLinks>
                        <LinkHoverWrapper first={true}>
                            <LoginModal />
                        </LinkHoverWrapper>
                        <LinkHoverWrapper>
                            <RegistrationModal />
                        </LinkHoverWrapper>
                    </SplitLinks>
                )}

                <AccountModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} />
            </NavbarWrapper>
        </>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to index authenticated pages, the easiest solution would be to use a skeleton while the authentication is happening. Just like [youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KqSz.png), you'll want to conditionally render some sort of skeleton **until** a context's `isLoading` value is `false` (default should be `true`). In short, don't just rely upon whether or not there's a user within the `user` state, instead rely upon **both** the `isLoading` state and `user` state.

**Demo** (while it doesn't use Next, the concept is the same):

[image: Edit Async Data Context (w/ Skeleton)]

Alternatively, you could render block the entire page and use `getInitialProps` (gIP) and pass the resulting `user` value to the provider and the component (any value returned from gIP will be added to `pageProps`). However, I wouldn't recommend it as it: Opts you out of static optimization, results in a slower TTFB (time to first byte) and technically would run for **every** page navigation since there's no way to retrieve the app contextual values from within gIP.

Alternative to context, you could use [a Redux provider](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper), which allows you to set and retrieve global application state from within gIP, but it introduces several layers of complexity: Setting up Redux with actions/reducers/constants and understanding the nuances with fetching cookies from the server using a client-side cookie. In short, it's not very developer friendly.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thank you for that. I will try to implement this now.

Comment: Just managed to get the Skeleton idea working. I really appreciate the time you took to compose this answer!